# Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter java object is not empty but converted xml tag is, unless some fields are annotated as XmlElement

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, jaxb2

I came across a strange situation while trying to convert Java to XML using Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter. 
The conversion worked, but only partially. 
One of my objects, ptpSearchResponse, who is not empty, appears as an empty XML tag after conversion.
My ptpSearchResponse object has a PtpContent object that in turn contains a List of PtpSolutions, which again contains a List of PtpPackages and so on and so on. All of them are serializable, have public getters etc (please find the code attached at the end).

My PtpSearchResponse class looked like this atm:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PtpSearchResponse extends AppResponse {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private PtpContent ptpContent;

    public PtpContent getPtpContent() {
        return ptpContent;
    }

    public void setPtpContent(PtpContent ptpContent) {
        this.ptpContent = ptpContent;
    }
}
```

Which should work imo, as according to the javadoc of Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter

> This converter can read classes annotated with {@link XmlRootElement} and {@link XmlType},and write classes annotated with with {@link XmlRootElement}, or subclasses thereof.

However, after conversion, I ended up with the following XML:

```
<ptpSearchResponse>
    <ptpContent/>
</ptpSearchResponse>
```

While debugging, I found that none of the getters of the Lists were being called so it made sense that the object was empty.
I then added & changed the @XmlAccessType to Fields or Public members, with no progress alas.

I then tinkered around and starting adding @XmlElement to different fields. In the end adding @XmlElement to the ptpContent object and the list of PtpSolutions, returned the full, complete tag, including the underlying Lists, without having to add @XmlElement to the underlying Lists!?

It makes no sense that I have to add @XmlElement to some fields, but not all and still end up with the complete, converted object.

**My concrete question is thus:**

How come adding @XmlRootElement is not enough for successful conversion and can someone explain the strange behavior where I have to add @XmlElement to some fields but not all to aqcuire my complete, converted object?

Please find the final, relevant code and final XML here:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PtpSearchResponse extends AppResponse {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement
    private PtpContent ptpContent;

    public PtpContent getPtpContent() {
        return PtpContent;
    }

    public void setPtpContent(PtpContent ptpContent) {
        this.ptpContent = ptpContent;
    }
}

public class PtpContent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement
    private List<PtpSolution> solutions = new ArrayList<PtpSolution>();

    public List<PtpSolution> getSolutions() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(solutions);
    }

    public void setSolution(List<PtpSolution> solutions) {
        if (solutions == null) {
            solutions = new ArrayList<PtpSolution>();
        }
        this.solutions = solutions;
    }
}

public class PtpSolution implements Serializable {
    @JsonIgnore
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String solutionId;

    private List<PtpSegment> ptpSegments = new ArrayList<PtpSegment>();
    private List<PtpPackage> ptpPackages = new ArrayList<PtpPackage>();

    public List<PtpSegment> getPtpSegments() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(ptpSegments);
    }

    public void setPtpSegments(List<PtpSegment> ptpSegments) {
        if (ptpSegments == null) {
            ptpSegments = new ArrayList<PtpSegment>();
        }
        this.ptpSegments = ptpSegments;
    }

    public List<PtpPackage> getPtpPackages() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(ptpPackages);
    }

    public void setPtpPackages(List<PtpPackage> ptpPackages) {
        if (ptpPackages == null) {
            ptpPackages = new ArrayList<PtpPackage>();
        }
        this.ptpPackages = ptpPackages;
    }
}

public abstract class AppResponse implements Serializable {
    @JsonIgnore
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Header header = new Header();

    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{domain}.do", params={"re_deeplink", "re_format=xml"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody PtpSearchResponse handleDeeplinkXml(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("domain") String domain, @RequestParam(value = "re_oper", required = false) String operator, @RequestParam(value = "ue_userhash", required = false) String hash, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "re_deeplink", required = true) String deeplink) {
    return handleDeeplink(request, domain, operator, hash, response, deeplink);
}

<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean id="jaxb2MessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Final XML:

```
<ptpSearchResponse>
    <header>
        <notices>
            <code>NOTICE_RE_PTP_RESARAIL_FALLBACK</code>
            <description>NOTICE_RE_PTP_RESARAIL_FALLBACK</description>
        </notices>
        <timestamp>2016-05-03T17:26:35+0200</timestamp>
    </header>
    <ptpContent>
        <solutions>
            <arrivalDate>06/05/2016</arrivalDate>
            <arrivalTime>13:41</arrivalTime>
            <departureDate>06/05/2016</departureDate>
            <departureTime>12:28</departureTime>
            <destinationCityCode>FRLIL</destinationCityCode>
            <destinationStationCode>FRADJ</destinationStationCode>
            <durationMins>73</durationMins>
            <inventoryCode>RR</inventoryCode>
            <originCityCode>FRPAR</originCityCode>
            <originStationCode>FRPNO</originStationCode>
            <ptpPackages>
                <classPrice>2</classPrice>
                <packageId>4</packageId>
                <price>
                    <amount>12.0</amount>
                    <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
                </price>
                <ptpFares>
                    <afterSaleRules>Non exchangeable, non refundable</afterSaleRules>
                    <applicableSegments>1</applicableSegments>
                    <fareName>2nd Cl Book Early Group of 5 Adults</fareName>
                    <flexibility>NON_FLEXIBLE</flexibility>
                    <numberOfPassengers>1</numberOfPassengers>
                    <passengerType>Adult</passengerType>
                    <saleRules>Advanced purchase.  Tickets must be issued immediately. For Group of 4,5,6 or 7.</saleRules>
                </ptpFares>
            </ptpPackages>
            <ptpPackages>
                <classPrice>2</classPrice>
                <packageId>5</packageId>
                <price>
                    <amount>15.0</amount>
                    <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
                </price>
                <ptpFares>
                    <afterSaleRules>Non exchangeable, non refundable</afterSaleRules>
                    <applicableSegments>1</applicableSegments>
                    <fareName>2nd Cl Book Early</fareName>
                    <flexibility>NON_FLEXIBLE</flexibility>
                    <numberOfPassengers>1</numberOfPassengers>
                    <passengerType>Adult</passengerType>
                    <saleRules>Advanced purchase.  Tickets must be issued immediately.</saleRules>
                </ptpFares>
            </ptpPackages>
            <ptpPackages>
                <classPrice>2</classPrice>
                <packageId>6</packageId>
                <price>
                    <amount>63.0</amount>
                    <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
                </price>
                <ptpFares>
                    <afterSaleRules>If ticket not used, 100% refundable/exchangeable up to train departure date with 5EUR charge within 30 days before departure. 50% refundable/exchangeable on train departure date before train departure hour with a maximum 15EUR charge. Thereafter, no refund allowed. EUR 9 tickets are usually non refundable. Subject to administrative charges in country of purchase.</afterSaleRules>
                    <applicableSegments>1</applicableSegments>
                    <fareName>2nd Cl Leisure 1 Adult</fareName>
                    <flexibility>SEMI_FLEXIBLE</flexibility>
                    <numberOfPassengers>1</numberOfPassengers>
                    <passengerType>Adult</passengerType>
                    <saleRules>Advance purchase recommended - Can be combined with a Leisure Week End Fare - Child up to 11 years inclusive</saleRules>
                </ptpFares>
            </ptpPackages>
            <ptpSegments>
                <arrivalDate>06/05/2016</arrivalDate>
                <arrivalTime>13:41</arrivalTime>
                <departureDate>06/05/2016</departureDate>
                <departureTime>12:28</departureTime>
                <destinationCityCode>FRLIL</destinationCityCode>
                <destinationStationCode>FRADJ</destinationStationCode>
                <equipmentCode>TGN</equipmentCode>
                <originCityCode>FRPAR</originCityCode>
                <originStationCode>FRPNO</originStationCode>
                <segmentId>1</segmentId>
                <trainName>TGV Nord</trainName>
                <trainNumber>7043</trainNumber>
            </ptpSegments>
            <solutionId>23783932</solutionId>
        </solutions>
            <arrivalDate>06/05/2016</arrivalDate>
            <arrivalTime>16:46</arrivalTime>
            <departureDate>06/05/2016</departureDate>
            <departureTime>15:41</departureTime>
            <destinationCityCode>FRLIL</destinationCityCode>
            <destinationStationCode>FRLLE</destinationStationCode>
            <durationMins>65</durationMins>
            <inventoryCode>RR</inventoryCode>
            <originCityCode>FRPAR</originCityCode>
            <originStationCode>FRPNO</originStationCode>
            <ptpPackages>
                <classPrice>2</classPrice>
                <packageId>4</packageId>
                <price>
                    <amount>12.0</amount>
                    <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
                </price>
                <ptpFares>
                    <afterSaleRules>Non exchangeable, non refundable</afterSaleRules>
                    <applicableSegments>5</applicableSegments>
                    <fareName>2nd Cl Book Early Group of 5 Adults</fareName>
                    <flexibility>NON_FLEXIBLE</flexibility>
                    <numberOfPassengers>1</numberOfPassengers>
                    <passengerType>Adult</passengerType>
                    <saleRules>Advanced purchase.  Tickets must be issued immediately. For Group of 4,5,6 or 7.</saleRules>
                </ptpFares>
            </ptpPackages>
            <ptpPackages>
                <classPrice>2</classPrice>
                <packageId>5</packageId>
                <price>
                    <amount>15.0</amount>
                    <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
                </price>
                <ptpFares>
                    <afterSaleRules>Non exchangeable, non refundable</afterSaleRules>
                    <applicableSegments>5</applicableSegments>
                    <fareName>2nd Cl Book Early</fareName>
                    <flexibility>NON_FLEXIBLE</flexibility>
                    <numberOfPassengers>1</numberOfPassengers>
                    <passengerType>Adult</passengerType>
                    <saleRules>Advanced purchase.  Tickets must be issued immediately.</saleRules>
                </ptpFares>
            </ptpPackages>
            <ptpPackages>
                <classPrice>2</classPrice>
                <packageId>6</packageId>
                <price>
                    <amount>63.0</amount>
                    <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
                </price>
                <ptpFares>
                    <afterSaleRules>If ticket not used, 100% refundable/exchangeable up to train departure date with 5EUR charge within 30 days before departure. 50% refundable/exchangeable on train departure date before train departure hour with a maximum 15EUR charge. Thereafter, no refund allowed. EUR 9 tickets are usually non refundable. Subject to administrative charges in country of purchase.</afterSaleRules>
                    <applicableSegments>5</applicableSegments>
                    <fareName>2nd Cl Leisure 1 Adult</fareName>
                    <flexibility>SEMI_FLEXIBLE</flexibility>
                    <numberOfPassengers>1</numberOfPassengers>
                    <passengerType>Adult</passengerType>
                    <saleRules>Advance purchase recommended - Can be combined with a Leisure Week End Fare - Child up to 11 years inclusive</saleRules>
                </ptpFares>
            </ptpPackages>
            <ptpSegments>
                <arrivalDate>06/05/2016</arrivalDate>
                <arrivalTime>16:46</arrivalTime>
                <departureDate>06/05/2016</departureDate>
                <departureTime>15:41</departureTime>
                <destinationCityCode>FRLIL</destinationCityCode>
                <destinationStationCode>FRLLE</destinationStationCode>
                <equipmentCode>TGN</equipmentCode>
                <originCityCode>FRPAR</originCityCode>
                <originStationCode>FRPNO</originStationCode>
                <segmentId>5</segmentId>
                <trainName>TGV Nord</trainName>
                <trainNumber>7559</trainNumber>
            </ptpSegments>
            <solutionId>23783936</solutionId>
        </solutions>
    </ptpContent>
</ptpSearchResponse>
```

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear but I tried that. I added @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) & @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER) to the PtpSearchResponse class but this didn't change anything.